# FastCGI and Nginx wrong index files priority

Tags: mono, indexing, nginx, fastcgi

I want to set up a Mono ASP.NET on Nginx, but it seems the index priority does not work.
If I use the example from http://www.mono-project.com/FastCGI_Nginx as following:

```
    location / {
        root   /srv/www/htdocs/;
        index index.htm index.html default.aspx Default.aspx;
        fastcgi_index Default.aspx;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

Then when I visit http://localhost/, it will always request `Default.aspx`, and if there is no such file, the web server will show a 404 error.

I tried to find answer by search the question, and I found this one:
[asp mvc home root not working with mono, fastcgi and nginx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946063/asp-mvc-home-root-not-working-with-mono-fastcgi-and-nginx)

So I guess I meet the same issue, then I modified the config file as following:

```
    location / {
        root   /srv/www/htdocs/;
        index index.htm index.html default.aspx Default.aspx;
        fastcgi_index /;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
```

The web server still requests `.aspx`-files as priority, even if I have only one `.aspx` file such as `random.aspx` in the `htdocs` folder, it will still show it before `index.htm`.

And then when I removed all FastCGI related config as following:

```
    location / {
        root   /srv/www/htdocs/;
        index index.htm index.html default.aspx Default.aspx;
    }
```

Only in this way the index priority works correctly.

So who can tell me, why does this happen? Do I have to modify any config file that is related to FastCGI?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure when your fastcgi settings in monoserve are pointing to a valid path.

```
fastcgi-mono-server2 /applications=www.domain1.xyz:/**:/var/www/www.domain1.xyz**/ /socket=tcp:127.0.0.1:9000
```

/var/www/www.domain1.xyz/ must point to the root directory of your web app.