# nginx bad gateway 502 with mono fastcgi

Tags: asp.net, razor, mono, nginx, fastcgi

Hello so I have been trying to get my website to run on mono (on ubuntu server) and I have followed [these tutorials](http://sourcecodebean.com/archives/serving-your-asp-net-mvc-site-on-nginx-fastcgi-mono-server4/1617) almost to the letter:

However when my directory is not blank fastcgi logs reveal this:

```
    Notice  Beginning to receive records on connection.
    Error   Failed to process connection. Reason: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

I am not really sure what this means, and depending on what I do I can get another error that tells me the resource cannot be found:

The resource cannot be found.

```
    Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.   Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
```

Requested URL: /Default.aspx/
Version information: Mono Runtime Version: 2.10.8 (tarball Thu Aug 16 23:46:03 UTC 2012)      ASP.NET Version: 4.0.30319.1

If I should provide some more information please let me know.

Edit:

I am now getting a nginx gateway error.

My nginx configuration file looks like this:

```
server {
    listen   2194;
    server_name localhost;
    access_log $HOME/WWW/nginx.log;

    location / {
      root $HOME/WWW/dev/;
      index index.html index.html default.aspx Default.aspx Index.cshtml;
      fastcgi_index Views/Home/; 
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
      include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    }
}
```

Running the entire thing with xsp4 I have discovered what the "Exception has been thrown by  the target of an invocation."

> Handling exception type TargetInvocationException Message is Exception
>   has been thrown by the target of an invocation. IsTerminating is set
>   to True System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has
>   been thrown by the target of an invocation.
>
> Server stack trace:  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke
>   (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr,
>   System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters,
>   System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in :0    at System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke (System.Object
>   obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in :0
>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectRecord.LoadData
>   (System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager manager,
>   ISurrogateSelector selector, StreamingContext context) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.ObjectManager.DoFixups () [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ReadNextObject
>   (System.IO.BinaryReader reader) [0x00000] in :0
>   at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.ReadObjectGraph
>   (BinaryElement elem, System.IO.BinaryReader reader, Boolean
>   readHeaders, System.Object& result,
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.Header[]& headers) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.NoCheckDeserialize
>   (System.IO.Stream serializationStream,
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.HeaderHandler handler) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize
>   (System.IO.Stream serializationStream) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.RemotingServices.DeserializeCallData
>   (System.Byte[] array) [0x00000] in :0    at (wrapper
>   xdomain-dispatch) System.AppDomain:DoCallBack (object,byte[]&,byte[]&)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:   ---> System.ArgumentException: Couldn't
>   bind to method 'SetHostingEnvironment'.   at
>   System.Delegate.GetCandidateMethod (System.Type type, System.Type
>   target, System.String method, BindingFlags bflags, Boolean ignoreCase,
>   Boolean throwOnBindFailure) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Delegate.CreateDelegate (System.Type type, System.Type target,
>   System.String method, Boolean ignoreCase, Boolean throwOnBindFailure)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at System.Delegate.CreateDelegate
>   (System.Type type, System.Type target, System.String method) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at
>   System.DelegateSerializationHolder+DelegateEntry.DeserializeDelegate
>   (System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at System.DelegateSerializationHolder..ctor
>   (System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext
>   ctx) [0x00000] in :0    at (wrapper
>   managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke
>   (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)   at
>   System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags
>   invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[]
>   parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in
>   :0    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at (wrapper xdomain-invoke) System.AppDomain:DoCallBack
>   (System.CrossAppDomainDelegate)   at (wrapper
>   remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:DoCallBack
>   (System.CrossAppDomainDelegate)   at
>   System.Web.Hosting.ApplicationHost.CreateApplicationHost (System.Type
>   hostType, System.String virtualDir, System.String physicalDir)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.WebServer.VPathToHost.CreateHost
>   (Mono.WebServer.ApplicationServer server, Mono.WebServer.WebSource
>   webSource) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.RealMain (System.String[] args, Boolean
>   root, IApplicationHost ext_apphost, Boolean quiet) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at Mono.WebServer.XSP.Server.Main
>   (System.String[] args) [0x00000] in :0

Answer (score 3):

In your nginx config, do this

```
fastcgi_index   /;
```

instead of this:

```
fastcgi_index Default.aspx;
```

and instead of this:

```
fastcgi_index Views/Home/;
```

You want the mono fastcgi server to see the base request.  In mvc3-land, there is no Default.aspx as everything is done via routes.  So, also remove this line:

```
index index.html index.html default.aspx Default.aspx Index.cshtml;
```

Another thing that can really bite you is that there are underlying assembly references to runtime 2 .dlls that have been compiled in libraries that your project is referencing.

I discovered this myself when I found out that nhibernate references from nuget were actually 3.5 .dlls.  This made it so that within a library, only some types were able to be loaded, while others threw crazy unrelated exceptions to what was actually going on.  I found this by using the csharp console.

The first exception that clued me into the underlying problem was this:

```
System.TypeLoadException: Could not load type
    at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Type:type_is_assignable_from (System.Type,System.Type)
```

Comment: Regarding the fastcgi_index, I think just removing the line is the same.

Answer (score 0):

the 404 url is "/Default.aspx/"

since it has it / at the end it's looking for a directory, I'm guessing you want it to look for a file Default.aspx instead?

what does your nginx config block for the fastcgi connection look like?

**UPDATE** (after requested info got added):

http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_index explains the fastcgi_index directive. The way you got it set up is kinda weird you're adding Views/Home/
to the $fastcgi_script_name of any direcory.

you probably want to set your fastcgi_index to Default.aspx (it will then pass any request for a directory as directory/default.aspx which I think is what you want)

you're also not setting your script_filename, which mono probably uses to know which file to run (that's the way it works with php/ruby fastcgi in any case).

you probably want something like the following for your nginx params in the location block:

```
fastcgi_index Default.aspx;
fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $HOME/WWW/dev/home/$fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8000;
include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
```

(the SCRIPT_FILENAME might possibly just be $fastcgi_script_name if I read your tutorial right)

as an aside, usually you'd set up the index and root directives once at the serverblock level so you don't have to repeat it for each location block, though since you only have the one location block it doesn't really matter.

Comment: Sorry for the long response time, I didn't see that anyone had left a response. I updated the main question with the things you asked for also now it is no longer looking for the Default.aspx/

Comment: ok, so now it's passing the request to mono, mono crashes, which explains the gateway error in nginx (mono isn't sending a request so nginx that process is down) -> the main problem is currently in your mono code, since it's crashing on the incoming request

Comment: Then maybe I'm not understand something fundamental about mono, but I am just using the sample code that is generated by Visual Studio Web Developer (using .net 4.0). My main goal is to get my site using the Razor View Engine working with mono

Comment: what's probably happening is that your monocode is getting some url it's not expecting and crashing on that, which would be bug. Always check your inputs, and return an error if it's unexpected. I updated my answer in light of the ngingx config you posted, try if that helps.

Comment: The Razor view engine doesn't give me a Default.aspx. I have cshtml files. Also this isn't my code, this is the default code that Visual Studio Web Developer generates, so I assume that is should work.

This is the tutorial I followed: 
http://sourcecodebean.com/archives/serving-your-asp-net-mvc-site-on-nginx-fastcgi-mono-server4/1617

Comment: right: your passing the webrequest to the fastcgi-listener on 127.0.0.1:8000. That listener is set up by the bash-script in your tutorial. The fastcgi_mono_server4 it sets up then parses the fastcgi call, and passes it on depending on the SCRIPT_FILENaME. If you don't have a Default.aspx, but something else as your appcode filename your incoming request name needs to be set up accordingly. Once your app gets the request it needs to do generate a response.

Comment: right now, it seems that: nginx is passing a request to fascgi_mono_server4 without a script_filename, and that apparently crashes the fastcgi_mono_server.